# find largest id within array object using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]
```

I know I can use max like this var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray) (if I have my array like this `[1,2,3]`) but since I have to loop through a list, I just wonder I can use loop to get the largest number;

```
$.each(function(){
//this.id
// how to continue here?
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use the `Math.max.apply` construct. Simply use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make an array of ids from the objects:

```
var maxId = Math.max.apply(Math, myList.map(function(o){ return o.id }));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using $.each

```
var items = [{ "id": 2 }, { "id": 1 }, { "id": 3 }];

var maxId = Number.MIN_VALUE;
$.each(items, function (index, item) {
    maxId = Math.max(maxId, item.id);
});
```

### Using ES5 forEach

```
var maxId = Number.MIN_VALUE;
items.forEach(function (item) {
    maxId = Math.max(maxId, item.id)
});
```

### Using ES5 reduce

```
var maxId = items.reduce(function (maxId, item) {
    return Math.max(maxId, item.id)
}, Number.MIN_VALUE);
```

### Using Underscore.js

Underscore.js has [max](http://underscorejs.org/#max) that works in old browsers too:

```
var maxId = _.max(items, function (item) { return item.id }).id;
```

Comment: why not using $.each?

Comment: If you support only modern browsers, native JavaScript functions (like map, forEach and reduce) are preferable.